# How to disable the popup modal in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

The website - https://www.soleretriever.com/raffles Has a popup modal to sign up when opening it. I want to disable this or find a way to click off it in selenium using python.

I have tried a few things but have not worked it out yet :/

Comment: @Lukemul69 Did u try out my solution? Did it help u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All u have to do is to click on a random position on the screen (other than the pop-up). You can use `ActionChains` in order to do it. Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.soleretriever.com/raffles')

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[6]/button')))

action = ctionChains(driver)

action.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(250, 0).click().perform()
```